# Ubuntu 17.10.1 stuck at start up, displaying "started WPA supplicant"

Tags: 17.10, startup

I' m trying to install ubuntu 17.10.1 on my laptop. The installation was successful, but when I reboot, the system just won' t start. It stuck at "started WPA supplicant" after displaying a few lines of texts, as shown below.[This is how it stucks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMIj8.jpg)

All inputs recieve no response. Please help.
P.S. The hardware of my laptop: i5 8400 and GTX 1060
P.P.S. I' ve also tried ubuntu 16.04, but it failed to start any graphic interface and I couldn' t have the GPU driver installed anyhow.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)